# Ingress controller not handling the traffic

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm using docker-for-desktop (docker for mac) and have installed ingress controller

```
$kubectl get pods -n ingress-nginx
NAME                                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-ingress-controller-78474696b4-8vmbr   1/1     Running   0          20d
```

but not able to handle the traffic for a sample service.
Here's a sample nginx service:

```
$kubectl run --image nginx webserver
$kubectl expose deploy webserver --port 80 --type NodePort
```

which runs as:

```
$kubectl get services
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP        40d
webserver    NodePort    10.109.250.166   <none>        80:31805/TCP   9m
```

and `sample-ingress.yaml`

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: webserver-sample
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /foo
        backend:
          serviceName: webserver
          servicePort: 80
```

and apply:

```
kubectl apply -f sample-ingress.yaml
```

ingress is running as:

```
$kubectl get ing
NAME               HOSTS   ADDRESS     PORTS   AGE
webserver-sample   *       localhost   80      7m
```

service is running as expected (which returns `200`):

```
curl http://localhost:31805/
```

but problem is I'm not able to hit `http://localhost/foo`

```
$curl http://localhost/foo
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused
```

Any suggestion on how to debug the issue would be really be appreciated

---

[Update] here's the list of all services as requested by @VKR

```
$kubectl get svc --all-namespaces -o wide
NAMESPACE       NAME            TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE   SELECTOR
default         kubernetes      ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP                      40d   <none>
default         webserver       NodePort    10.107.135.81    <none>        80:32361/TCP                 9h    run=webserver
docker          compose-api     ClusterIP   10.108.251.142   <none>        443/TCP                      40d   com.docker.deploy-namespace=docker,com.docker.fry=compose.api,com.docker.image-tag=v0.4.12
ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx   NodePort    10.106.47.48     <none>        80:31448/TCP,443:31512/TCP   20d   app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx,app.kubernetes.io/part-of=ingress-nginx
kube-system     kube-dns        ClusterIP   10.96.0.10       <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP                40d   k8s-app=kube-dns
```

and also here's describe ingress:

```
$kubectl describe ing webserver-sample
Name:             webserver-sample
Namespace:        default
Address:          localhost
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<none>)
Rules:
  Host  Path  Backends
  ----  ----  --------
  *
        /foo   webserver:80 (10.1.0.151:80)
Annotations:
  kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:  {"apiVersion":"extensions/v1beta1","kind":"Ingress","metadata":{"annotations":{"nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target":"/"},"name":"webserver-sample","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"rules":[{"http":{"paths":[{"backend":{"serviceName":"webserver","servicePort":80},"path":"/foo"}]}}]}}

  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target:  /
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age    From                      Message
  ----    ------  ----   ----                      -------
  Normal  CREATE  9m42s  nginx-ingress-controller  Ingress default/webserver-sample
  Normal  UPDATE  9m30s  nginx-ingress-controller  Ingress default/webserver-sample
```

Comment: If your service is running on port `31805`, you have to use `servicePort: 31805` in `Ingress`.

Comment: Can you access your services directly by NodePort?

Comment: @menya yep `curl http://localhost:31805/` returns fine

Comment: @ZawThanoo question is about accessing the service via Ingress controller...service is running fine

Comment: show all your services `kubectl get svc --all-namespaces -o wide`. And can you describe how you installed ingress controller

Comment: @VKR please look at updated post for list of all services.
I've installed the controller from here https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/
altho the way to generate the controller seems to be changed

Comment: So your ingress http servcice listen on `NodePort:31448`, it will rewrite your request `/foo` to `webserver:80`. I think it will work by `curl http://localhost:31448/foo`

Answer (score 0):

Just reproduced your case in Docker for Windows - for me it works fine.
Tried to expose with both NodePort and ClusterIP options - result is the same - it works
Below is example using ClusterIP  `kubectl expose deploy webserver --port 80 --type ClusterIP`

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> kubectl get pods -n ingress-nginx
NAME                                        READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-ingress-controller-78474696b4-29fps   1/1       Running   0          2m

PS D:\> kubectl.exe get svc --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE       NAME            TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
default         kubernetes      ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP                      26m
default         webserver       ClusterIP      10.110.218.48    <none>        80/TCP                       8m
docker          compose-api     ClusterIP      10.105.175.29    <none>        443/TCP                      25m
ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx   LoadBalancer   10.101.213.113   localhost     80:31191/TCP,443:32056/TCP   19m
kube-system     kube-dns        ClusterIP      10.96.0.10       <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP                26m
```

yaml I used:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: webserver-sample
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /foo
        backend:
          serviceName: webserver
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /bar
        backend:
          serviceName: webserver
          servicePort: 80
```

Curl for `/foo` and `/bar` returns `308 Permanent Redirect` (that is expected and works by design)

```
PS D:\> curl http://localhost/foo
curl : 308 Permanent Redirect
nginx/1.15.10
At line:1 char:1
+ curl http://localhost/foo
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
PS D:\> curl http://localhost/bar
curl : 308 Permanent Redirect
nginx/1.15.10
At line:1 char:1
+ curl http://localhost/bar
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Curl for `/smth` returns `404`

```
PS D:\> curl http://localhost/smth
curl : 404 Not Found
nginx/1.15.10
At line:1 char:1
+ curl http://localhost/smth
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Try to reinstall all from scratch using latest instruction and yamls. It should work for sure